# How much of this `inline for` will be abbreviated at comptime in Zig?

Tags: metaprogramming, zig

I'm trying a thing that iterates over the fields of a `struct` and does a different action according to the type of the field:

```js
const std = @import("std");

const S = struct {
    letter: u8,
    number: u64,
};

pub fn main() void {
    var result: i64 = 0;
    var s = S{ .letter = 'a', .number = 77 };
    inline for ([_][]const u8{ "letter", "number" }) |fname| {
        var v = @field(s, fname);
        switch (@TypeOf(v)) {
            u8 => result += 1,
            u64 => result += 2,
            else => unreachable,
        }
    }
    std.debug.print("result={}\n", .{result});
}
```

My question is: will the field differentiation logic (the `switch`) happen at `comptime`?, i.e. will the actual compile program be similar to

```rust
result += 1;
result += 2;
```

-- or will it be more like

```js
const type1 = u8;
switch (type1) {
  u8 => result += 1,
  u64 => result += 2,
  else => unreachable,
}
const type2 = u64;
switch (type2) {
  u8 => result += 1,
  u64 => result += 2,
  else => unreachable,
}
```

I was assuming these switches were unnecessary since everything required to compute these things are known at compile time, but apparently the `switch` is being evaluated, because if I declare `S.number` to be `u32`, for example, the execution panics at the `unreachable`.

If that is the case, how can I rewrite this to make it more performant?

Answer (score 1):

`inline for` is unrolled and the code for each iteration is inlined into the resulting code for compilation. In other words, this

```
inline for (...) {
    // some code ...
}
```

becomes

```
// some code ...
// some code ...
```

> If that is the case, how can I rewrite this to make it more performant?

This doesn't really have affect on performance, because in release mode the compiler will optimize this code. For example, I've used [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/4nMfKK3xe) to check the output assembly for a similar code and the compiler ended up reducing it all down to:

```
example.main:
        push    rax
        mov     rdi, rsp
        mov     qword ptr [rsp], 3
        call    "log.scoped(.default).err__anon_3359"
        pop     rax
        ret
```

Comment: I get this, but what about the `switch` stuff? Will it be ran on every iteration of the inline loop? Or will it be optimized out given that `@TypeOf(v)` is known at compile time? I tried checking on godbolt, but it produced a lot of assembly for my code and I didn't understand it.

Comment: Yes, `switch` is there for each iteration. At least in debug mode. But in release mode, it's removed during optimization.

Comment: I've provided a link to a godbolt in the answer. You can search in the assembly for "example.main".

Answer (score 1):

> My question is: will the field differentiation logic (the switch) happen at comptime?, i.e. will the actual compile program be similar to

> ```
> result += 1;
> result += 2;
> ```

Yes, but not because of the `inline for`, it's because the thing you're switching on is `comptime` only, a `type`. That means the entire switch will be replaced by whichever branch was hit at comptime, the `inline for` just lets you do this more than once.

So if we deconstruct it step by step (as the compiler would do) it might look something like this:

Step 1:

```rs
inline for ([_][]const u8{ "letter", "number" }) |fname| {
  var v = @field(s, fname);
  switch (@TypeOf(v)) {
    u8 => result += 1,
    u64 => result += 2,
    else => unreachable,
  }
}
```

Step 2:

```rs
{
  // fname gets replaced by the actual value
  var v = @field(s, "letter");
  switch (@TypeOf(v)) {
    u8 => result += 1,
    u64 => result += 2,
    else => unreachable,
  }
}
{
  var v = @field(s, "number");
  switch (@TypeOf(v)) {
    u8 => result += 1,
    u64 => result += 2,
    else => unreachable,
  }
}
```

Step 3:

```rs
{
  // v is removed in non-debug build modes
  // because it isnt referenced in the final result

  // the switch is replaced with whatever branch was hit
  result += 1;
}
{
  result += 2;
}
```

You can see this when you inspect the assembly code generated, even in debug mode it's just equivalent to:

```rs
var v1 = @field(s, "letter");
result += 1;
var v2 = @field(s, "number");
result += 2;
```

Also, recommendation for iterating over a type's fields is to use either `@typeInfo(T).Struct.fields`, or `std.meta.fields` like this:

```rs
inline for (@typeInfo(S).Struct.fields) |field| {
  switch (field.type) {
    // ...
  }
}
```